# FCM clearing notification from system tray (payload type both data and notification)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am sending a notification from my server using FCM to my users that contain both a data and notification type payload.

based on the docs:

> Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>   foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your launcher Activity.

everything works fine, the notification shows up on the system tray now i would like to show that notification for about 20 seconds and then let it disappear from tray if the user did not click or do anything. (so methods with a handler wont work since the user is not clicking)

Am really not sure how to go about this, can someone please help!

Comment: that wont work, since the user is not clicking on the notification and no activity is launching. or am i wrong?

Comment: I think your only option is to send a data-only message and generate the  notification yourself in `onMessageReceived()`.  When you build the notification, use `NotificationCompat.Builder.setTimeoutAfter()` for automatic clearing.

Comment: hey bob, thanks for your feedback. i tried to implement that but i cant seem to get it right, can you please provide a code example for reference or something

Comment: There is example code here (scroll down about 7 screens): https://medium.com/@nileshsingh/how-to-add-push-notification-capability-to-your-android-app-a3cac745e56e